# What should I do about the battery light?

Tags: battery

I have a 2008 Honda Accord and I just bought a new battery and the battery light came on what should I do

Answer (score 1):

The battery light is an indicator the charging system has a problem.

Take the car to have the charging system tested. The alternator may have failed or be failing.